# htaccess redirect exact match, exclude all query strings

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect `http://domain.com/search` to `http://domain.com`

However I also have urls that looks like `http://domain.com/search?q=someword`

At the moment I have :

```
redirectMatch 301 http://domain.com/search$ http://domain.com
```

And even though it redirects correctly the `http://domain.com/search` url, it also redirects any `http://domain.com/search?q=someword` url to `http://domain.com/?q=someword`, which I do not want.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `mod_rewrite` instead of `mod_alias` in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/?$ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

Comment: were already present in my htaccess file, so I just added the 3rd line but it still doesn't work

Comment: If you're using this (my) code, you must remove your `RedirectMatch` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `?` to the end of your target:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/search$ http://domain.com/?
```

This, however, will cause a `?` to appear at the end of the URL in the browser's location bar. If you use mod_rewrite instead, you won't see the `?`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?search$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: that ended up removing the string completely. I just want to leave the url intact if it has the ?q=someword at the end, not remove it completely

Comment: I guess it's my fault, I see now that I didn't explain my situation correctly in the first place