# .htaccess Redirect for exact page but not query strings

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, buddypress

We have been trying to create a dynamic redirect for the BuddyPress message Compose page using .htaccess rules. I would like for the Compose area to be inaccessible, but when someone clicks the "Private Message" button on someone's profile, they can still get to the page and send a message to the user.

I found this post, but I can't get my redirect to work - [htaccess redirect exact match, exclude all query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291558/htaccess-redirect-exact-match-exclude-all-query-strings)

The Compose area redirects to the home page fine, but when a query string is added during an attempt to message the user, we are redirected to the home page, but the query string remains in the URL.

Here is what I am using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^members/([\w-]+)/messages/compose/?$ / [L,R=302]
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts keep it up. Could you please confirm 2 things: 1st- you want to redirect a URL OR forbid access to it? 2nd- where I'd your htaccess file present on server?

Comment: Try using `QSD` flag in your rule. QSD flag is used to discard the old query string from new URL .`[L,R=302,QSD]` should work.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 A redirect would be fine here I think. It would prevent any functionality from potentially breaking. The file is in the /public_html/ folder. Thanks for your suggestion, Amit. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me :(

Comment: @Nifty, ok so from url `http://localhost:80/members/test-test/messages/compose/` to which url? kindly confirm on same once.

Comment: @Nifty Well , from your question what I understand is , "When the URL path is `/members/foobar/messages/compose/?querystring` you want it to redirect to `/` instead of `/?querystring` . Is this what you want?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 using your example,` http://localhost:80/members/test-test/messages/compose/ ` should redirect to the home page `/` but when attempting to message someone, the URL will change to something similar to the following `http://localhost:80/members/test-test/messages/compose/?r=buddypressuser&_wpnonce=12345678910 `. It should then load the Compose page as normal ready to message the user. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @amit-verma I actually would like the opposite. A request to `/compose/` with a query string (in this case, to send a private message, such as `/members/foobar/messages/compose/?r=buddypressuser&_wpnonce=12345678910`) should load the page as normal. If the request is direct to the `/members/foobar/messages/compose/` page, it will redirect to the home page `/`.

Comment: @Nifty, ok cool, do you have any other rules also in your htaccess? If not then please do confirm if compose is a PHP/html file which will serve your URL? OR it's internally rewrite to index.php file?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes. There are other rules, such as the default WordPress rewrite rules. I believe WordPress internally rewrites to index.php file to display the home page `/`, if I am correct? We use the Post name permalink option in WordPress.

Comment: @Nifty, sure, one more question is query string part `buddypressuser&_wpnonce=12345678910` is dynamic? Or for this specific url it will be always same?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 No problem. `buddypressuser&_wpnonce=12345678910` will be dynamic. For example, `buddypressuser` will be the username of the person and the part with `12345678910` will be automatically generated by BuddyPress/WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

```
# Redirect only when there is no query string present
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^members/([\w-]+)/messages/compose/$ / [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Remember to place the code at the top of your htaccess or before other directives .

```
RewriteEngine on

#Redirect the URL to / if no query string is present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^members/([\w-]+)/messages/compose/?$ / [L,R=302]
```